# Split column into date and values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, split, data-science

I have dataframe as below:

[image: screenshot of problem]

[image: screenshot]

I need to split this into date and value. If someone experienced this problem, please help

Comment: I don't quite understand what you need to split.
Can you give a more explicit example of your expected input and output?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please take the time to read this post on [how to provide a great pandas example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) as well as how to provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and revise your question accordingly. These tips on [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) may also be useful.

Comment: Doesn't look like a single column, the date seems to be the index and EGT is the only column. Look up on converting index to column in pandas.

Comment: The dataframe has picked up your date column as an index. Try reset_index() (https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html)

Comment: I'm not sure you have a dataframe there, might be a serie too. Then you could try to add: `.to_frame()`.

Comment: Thanks for your replies, especially DrBenway - reset_index() solved this problem